# Not able to load images and json files locally in react js with HTTPS=true in react app

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, axios

I have created a react app using create-react-app and running it using command
**set HTTPS=true&&npm start**. Also, I'm using the axios for AJAX call. 
In the app, I want to use the mock data from the JSON files which are in the local directory under the **src/shared/mockdata** folder but somehow I'm getting the **404 error/ Cannot GET /assets/logo-80x80.png** though I have given the full path **https://localhost:3000/shared/mockdata/current.json** and this same thing is happening with loading the images as well.
I used **npm run eject** and  tried it by setting the value false of **disableDotRule of histodisableDotRuleryApiFallback** in **webpackDevserver.config.js file**.

Comment: You have to either load your png and json files via importing them and having a matching webpack loader configured or you have to put them in your output folder. Webpack won't automatically copy all files and folder structures from src to your output folder.

Comment: Thanks, @xDreamCoding, It worked in the output folder. But I think it's not a correct way to read files from the output.